# How to copy a newest file from Docker container to local machine

Tags: docker

How can I copy the newest file in docker directory to local directory? I know that I can use `docker cp` but I have to know what file I have to copy. I can figure it out inside docker container by sorting the files at taking the last one but I don't know how to extract this path outside the container so that I could use `docker cp`.

Comment: this is what you talking about? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331645/extract-file-from-docker-image

Comment: What's actually in the container, and why does an individual file in its filesystem matter?  Can you retrieve it maybe using a `curl` command to retrieve it from the HTTP service the container is running?  Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: The file in docker contain connection settings for jupyter kernel. To create this file I have to run a command inside container. But once I create it and figure out its path, i dont know how to pass this path to `docker cp` command in the same powershell script (I want to automate this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a Docker image with 5 files with different timestamps

```
FROM debian
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo a > ahsgdfkjhagsdkf && sleep 1 && \
    echo b > hsagdkfjhasgdkf && sleep 1 && \
    echo c > ahsdgfkhjasgdfk && sleep 1 && \
    echo d > hasgdfkjhasgdkh && sleep 1 && \
    echo e > kasdflkjhasldfk
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Build and run it with

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -d --name mytest test
```

Then we can use `ls -t | head -1` to find the newest file. Combine that with `tar` to compress it in the container, send it to stdout and then decompress it on the host, like this

```
docker exec mytest /bin/sh -c 'tar -czO $(ls -t | head -1)' | tar -zxf -
```

The newest file, kasdflkjhasldfk, has now been copied to the host.

We need to execute `/bin/sh` in the container and pass it the command in quotes. If we didn't have it in quotes, `$(ls -t | head -1)` would be evaluated on the host and we would pass a filename to `tar` that exists on the host, but not in the container.

By having the command that should be run in the container in quotes, `$(ls -t | head -1)` is evaluated in the container and we get the correct filename.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case the file which I want to copy is create inside container and I cannot do anything else inside this powershell window (it cretes python kernel). I have to open new Powershell window to get the copy the file. So currently I stucked on this (question edited)

Comment: OK I solved the problem with the use of Python and `subprocess` module

Comment: @Berker Unclear why python is required to do anything with Docker